# Navigate to subsequent screen React Navigation 6 / React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong with the below:

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

I’ve got this in App.js (trimmed down of course):

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
           <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={Home}
            />
           <Stack.Screen
              name="Groups"
              component={Groups}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Group Detail"
              component={GroupDetail}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
}
```

Now, when I go from Home to Groups and then try to call `navigation.navigate("GroupDetail");`

I get this error:
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"GroupDetail"} was not handled by any navigator.

```
Do you have a screen named 'GroupDetail'?
```

Of course, I do have that screen and have checked the imports.

What am I missing here? I need to just push from `Home`, to `Groups` then to `Group Detail`.

I’ve tried the Nested Navigator documentation, but I think think it applies here (didn’t work anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I had the `name` wrong.

Instead of `Group Detail`, it needed to be `GroupDetail`.